# WPF DragEnter not firing on Image

Tags: c#, wpf

I have an image that is inside of a tab item:

```
       <TabItem x:Name="tabThreeTb" Header="Photos" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" Margin="1,0,-1,0">
            <Grid x:Name="tabThreeBdy" Background="#FFE5E5E5">
                <Rectangle Fill="#FFE5E5E5" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="369" Margin="12,13,0,0" Stroke="Black" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467">
                    <Rectangle.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect/>
                    </Rectangle.Effect>
                </Rectangle>
                <TextBox x:Name="picNotesTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="415" Margin="498,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="299"/>
                <Button x:Name="nxtPhotoBtn" Content="Next" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="404,403,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                <Button x:Name="prevPhotoBtn" Content="Prev" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,403,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
                <Label x:Name="photoNumLbl" Content="1 of 4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="226,401,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="42"/>
                <Image x:Name="photoTabImage" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="369" Margin="12,13,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="467" AllowDrop="True" DragEnter="photoTabImage_DragEnter"/>
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
```

I am trying to use drag and drop to allow for the addition of photos to to the list that contains paths for the image source, though I can't seem to be able to fire the DragEnter routine...

I would like the drag and drop functionality to only be alive when the content is being dragged over the Image bounds.

Is there something I need to do for an Item that is nested in a tab control to allow this?

Comment: `Image` not call `DragEnter` and `DragOver`. This bug wpf. Use other controls override `Image`. For example `Label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try add

```
    <Label HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=HorizontalAlignment}" 
           Height="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=Height}"
           Width="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=Width}"
           Margin="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=Margin}"
           VerticalAlignment="{Binding ElementName=photoTabImage, Path=VerticalAlignment}"
           AllowDrop="True" Drop="ContainerDrop" DragOver="ContainerDragOver"/>
```

after Image, and use event DragOver

if you need analyze drop object then add next code inside you class

```
    private void ContainerDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      foreach (string format in e.Data.GetFormats())
      {
        sb.AppendLine("Format:" + format);
        try
        {
          object data = e.Data.GetData(format);
          sb.AppendLine("Type:" + (data == null ? "[null]" : data.GetType().ToString()));
          sb.AppendLine("Data:" + data.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
          sb.AppendLine("!!CRASH!! " + ex.Message);
        }
        sb.AppendLine("=====================================================");
      }
      Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
    }
    private void ContainerDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
      e.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy;
      e.Handled = true;
    }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you!!  I was unaware of that bug with WPF...  Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in that your app for some reason can't proceed standard events set. To fix that switch it to the tunneling model, by simply replacing your events on Preview versions (for instance replace `DragEnter="photoTabImage_DragEnter"` on to the `PreviewDragEnter="photoTabImage_DragEnter"`)

Best regards,
Maks!